# Portable Power to 9 volts

Tags: power

Hope everyone is keeping safe :)

I am wanting to build a portable power supply with a slight difference.

I had a quick look on the site and I cant find what time looking for.

I want to use my spare 18650 batterys and essentially convert it to 9 Volts.

As a temp solution I have my batterys (2 in series that I charge up separatly) then it goes to a CN6009 then it comes out at 9 Volts to the socket I need.

In an ideal world I could do with some more batterys to make it last longer and some type of charging circuit (a mobile phone charger thing)

I am a bit of a noob to all this so please be nice :)

Also if you could answer with a drawing that would be amazing EG[image: my example]

Thank you inadvance

Comment: Please explain what a CN6009 is and add a link to its data sheet (and I don't mean a link to peebay or bang-bad or shamazon or maliexpress). Then explain what power output you want and how many Ah you need.

Comment: The TP4056 (the charger in the pic) is not going to do you justice for anything above 1S. You'll need a 4S battery charger if you want to charge 4 batteries in series, with some type of Battery Management System (BMS) for balance charging and Overvoltage, Undervoltage, and Overcurrent protection.

Comment: What is the load, and how much current does it draw at 9V?

Comment: So its for a guitar pedal (thats why it needs to be 9volts) at 1amp. the cn6009 details at at the bottom of this comment.                                                                                                                       http://kit-amp.com/step-up-dc-dc-converter-cn6009-en

Comment: Which guitar pedal?

Answer (score 1):

The CN6009 is a boost converter, so the input voltage cannot be higher than 9 V. Therefore your choices for battery configuration are either 2S2P (series combination of 2 x 2 cells in parallel) giving 8.4 V max, or 4P (all four batteries in parallel) giving 4.2 V max.

The advantages of a simple parallel (3.7 V nominal) setup are:-

1. Batteries do not have to be precisely matched.
2. can use an odd number of cells.
3. Don't need a BMS (Battery Management System) to maintain cell balance.
4. Can use a commonly available 1 cell charging module and 5 V 'phone charger'
   power supply.

Some likely disadvantages are:-

1. Lower boost converter efficiency due to higher input current.
2. Probably lower output current capability.
3. Long charging time due to limited current output of typical 1 cell chargers.

To use a 4 cell series battery (14.8 V nominal, 16.8 V max) you would need 4 matched cells, a 4 cell BMS (either with balancing, or combined with a sophisticated balancing charger), a 4 cell charger with suitable power supply, and a buck converter to drop the voltage to 9 V. This could be a bit more efficient, but also much more expensive and more complex.

For a 'bit of a noob' I recommend keeping it simple. Paralleling cells is easy and relatively safe (just make sure they have the same voltage when joined), and you may already have everything you need!

Comment: Brill thanks for that I'll go parallel. what would be the best charger?  how could I wire up charger to the cells to the cn6009? thanks

Comment: What is 'best' depends on what is important to you. 4 x 18650 cells in parallel will probably have a capacity of ~10Ah, so 1A charger would take ~10 hours to fully charge them from 'flat'. A 2A charger would take ~5 hours. Here's a module that charges at 2A:- https://www.ebay.com/itm/Charging-Charger-Module-1S-3-7V-2S-7-4V-Lithium-Lipo-Li-ion-18650-Battery-8-4V/193432933925. This module can be wired directly to the battery, though you might want to add a 'PCM' (Protection Circuit Module) to prevent over-discharge if the pedal is accidentally left on.

Comment: Another option is an external 'universal' charger with built-in power supply. More expensive, but far more useful! eg. https://www.skyrc.com/iMAX_B6AC_V2_Charger  The charger output would plug into a suitable socket on the battery box. For safety the connector should be a special battery plug (eg. XT60) to prevent plugging something inappropriate into it.